# Display Selected values of one SelectList in another SelectList

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select, selectlist, actionsupport

I have 2 `<apex:selectList>`. The values of 1 selectList (called Available) are populated from Query.  When user selects values from this multi-select selectList, I want to show them immediately in another selectList (called Chosen) just beside it.  I'm using actionSupport for this but doesn't seem to work.

Here are the 2 selectLists.  On "onclick" event, I'm calling a controller method to put the `tasksSelected` into `TasksChosen`

```
<apex:repeat value="{!MapDep}" var="deptKey">
    <apex:selectList id="Available" value="{!tasksSelected}" multiselect="true" >   
      <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!AddSelectedTasks}" rerender="chosen"/>
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!MapDep[deptKey]}"/>
    </apex:selectList>         

    <apex:selectList id="chosen" value="{!tasksSelectedByUser}" multiselect="true">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!TasksChosen}" />
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:repeat>
```

But the `tasksSelected` values from the 1st selectList is null!!

```
    public void AddSelectedTasks(){     
        System.debug('on click------>'+tasksSelected);
        for(String t:tasksSelected){
            TasksChosenList.add(new SelectOption(t, t));
        }       
    }

    public List<SelectOption> TasksChosenList = new List<SelectOption>();

    public List<SelectOption> getTasksChosen(){     
        return TasksChosenList;
    }
```

Above is the Add SelectedTasks Method, the debug that I added is giving null.  How do I solve this?  Any hints?

**Note:  The two selectLists are inside an `<apex:repeat>`!**

Comment: Try to change event="onChange"

Comment: hmm I tried, no change! ;)

Comment: FYI,The two selectLists are inside an <apex:repeat>.  Does that hint anything

Comment: Did you tried putting the two selectLists inside a single `<apex:actionRegion>`?

Comment: BTW, your variable names are different. In your `AddSelectedTasks` you are adding the `SelectOption` to `TasksChosenList`, but in your `apex:selectList` you are using the `TaskChosen` field -> `<apex:selectOptions value="{!TasksChosen}" />`

Comment: @smukov oh, I have added the TaskChosen and TasksChosenList related code in the question.

Comment: Not a solution. But have you explored possibility of using Salesforce multiselect picklist component. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html

Comment: Best if you add to your question the declaration and getter/setter for `tasksSelected` as that is ending up `null`.

Comment: I double checked the getter setter! I setter for the 2nd one, was pointing to the 1st one, my bad.  Thanks all for the comments and time

Answer (score 1):

Figured out, the setter for `TasksSelectedByUser` was wrong, my bad! Thanks @Keith C

```
public void setTasksSelectedByUser(String[] TasksSelectedByUser){
    this.TasksSelectedByUser = TasksSelectedByUser;
}
```

Thanks All, for the comments!